# LINQ - How to get data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have my **Table1** that contains the following columns.

[image]

My **Table2** contains

[image]

I am currently getting all the rows from Table1 that are in a date range as follows:

```cs
dbRowList = context.Table1.Where(x => x.dateTime > from && x.dateTime < to).ToList();
```

However, I would like to also get only the rows that, for the same `idCycle` in Table2 (=id of Table1), have the 'label' field with certain string content.

How to join it or query it using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Table1 join Table2 on `Table1.id` = `Table2.idCycle`.
2. Filter for the date range for the records in Table1 and Label in Table2.
3. Select all columns (or specify the column that is required) from Table1.

```cs
var result = (from a in context.Table1
    join b in context.Table2 on a.id equals b.idCycle 
    where (a.dateTime > from && a.dateTime < to)
    and b.label = /* Value for Label to filter */
    select a
)
.ToList();
```